# Chord Theory: Verse, Bridge and Chorus

Tags: theory, chords

I am a beginner/intermediate level guitarist. From time to time I come up with a nice sounding chord progression. I have little knowledge of music theory, and I am struggling to make this chord sequence evolve into a bridge or a chorus. I see small pieces of answers to other questions but usually applied to a specific example.

Is there any way to, given a chord progression, methodically deduce a bridge and a chorus (probably multiple ways)? Are these methods depend on the scale we are in? The key? The starting chord progression?

I understand in music there is never a magical formula, but does theory provide an easy-to-use framework to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of well used ideas that feature. A verse will end on the key chord, often use the dominant seventh version of that chord, to lead into the chorus starting on IV. The end of that chorus will usually finish on V (or V7) which in turn leads back to I for the start of another verse.

Another idea can work in two ways. Either going from minor in the verse to relative major for the chorus, or the opposite way, if the verse is in Am, for example, the chorus goes to C major.

Those are only a couple of examples - the best way to answer the question is to do a lot of listening to already existing songs, and work out what happens in them. The key a song is in has no impact as to what chord pattern works - although usually those chords involved are diatonic - as in 'from that key'. Sometimes with the addition of V of V, to signal a slight modulation.

One other idea is using chords from the *parallel key*.

So, in C, for instance, there could be a pool of - C Dm Em F G Am Bo, D (V of V) Cm Do Eb Fm Gm Ab Bb, and E (V of Am). That's got to be enough to make several songs!